# How to install VMware in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, vmware

I want to install VMware in ubuntu20.04

but I don't know what version to install and how to install

I need your help.

thank you.

Comment: Do you really mean vmware and not virtualbox?

Comment: VirtualBox is a good alternative, because VMWare is not free. To install Virtualbox use `sudo apt install virtualbox` from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-vmware-workstation-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Doesn't command a specific version in the instructions but it makes note of one (unless the link it provides passively implies which one to use).
Provides step by step instructions.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.